# Adding an object from Object A into Object B without creating new object ? HIBERNATE

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many, hibernate-mapping, cascade

Lets say I have two objects, say one is a User object and the other is a State Object. The state object is basically the 50 states of America so it doesn't ever have to change. The user object however has a Collection of States where the user has been. So like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tbl_users")
class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id", unique=true, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column(name="user_name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity=State.class, orphanRemoval = false)
    @Column(name="states")
    private Collection<State> states;

    //getters and setters
}
```

and the States entity looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tbl_states")
class State {

   @Id
   @Column(name="id", unique=true, nullable=false)
   private int id;

   @Column(name="state")
   private String state;

   // getters and setters
}
```

Code for adding user (using hibernate):

```
public int addUser(User user) {
    em.persist(user);
    em.flush();
    return user.getId();
}
```

Code for getting state by id:

```
public State getStateById(int id) {
    return em.createQuery("SELECT s FROM State s WHERE s.id =:id, State.class)
            .setParameter("id", id)
            .getSingleResult();
}
```

but when I try to create a User and pick several states, I get a PSQLException:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "uk_g6pr701i2pcq7400xrlb0hns"
2017-06-21T22:54:35.959991+00:00 app[web.1]:   Detail: Key (states_id)=(5) already exists.
```

I tried looking up the Cascade methods to see if I could use any, but Cascade.MERGE and Cascade.PERSIST seem to do the same thing, and the rest I don't think I need (REMOVE, DETACH, etc). My question is:
How do I add states to the User object without having that error?

Comment: How do you retrieve your states objects before adding them to your user object ?

Comment: @AbassA I do a getStateById() for each and it returns the state Object into an array list, and then I add that array list to the user, using the setter method

Comment: Could you provide the complete code where you process the save method. why do you have a @Column on top of your collection attribute, you don't need this, and i imagine thta you have a table user_state which supports the relation ?

Comment: @AbassA on the frontend or backend?

Comment: On the backend the code you use for making your save and where you use your getStateById method

Comment: @AbassA just added both

Comment: Ok your error seems occurs on your relation table user_state, as indicated : **state_id** is a field on your relation table and not your state table .try to verify that you dont have any constraint on this table ? have you created this table manually or you've used hibernate hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto ?

Comment: @AbassA it was created automatically with hibernate

Comment: Ok i see, when you declare a oneToMany hibernate create automatically a unicty constraint you must change it to ManyToMany relation to allow multiple records on state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works:

```
class Example {

    @Test
    public void workingTest() {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("testPU");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

        // Creating three states
        State alabama = new State(state: 'Alabama');
        State louisiana = new State(state: 'Louisiana');
        State texas = new State(state: 'Texas');
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(alabama);
        em.persist(louisiana);
        em.persist(texas);
        em.getTransaction().commit();

        List<State> states = em.createQuery('FROM State').getResultList();

        // Assert only three states on DB
        assert states.size() == 3;

        User userFromAlabama = new User();
        User userFromAlabamaAndTexas = new User();

        em.getTransaction().begin();
        State alabamaFromDB = em.find(State, alabama.getId());
        State texasFromDB = em.find(State, texas.getId());
        userFromAlabama.getStates().add(alabamaFromDB);
        userFromAlabamaAndTexas.getStates().add(alabamaFromDB);
        userFromAlabamaAndTexas.getStates().add(texasFromDB);

        em.persist(userFromAlabama);
        em.persist(userFromAlabamaAndTexas);
        em.getTransaction().commit();

        states = em.createQuery('FROM State').getResultList();

        // Assert only three states on DB again
        assert states.size() == 3;

        // Assert one user
        User userFromDB = em.find(User, userFromAlabama.getId());
        assert userFromDB.getStates().size() == 1;

        userFromDB = em.find(User, userFromAlabamaAndTexas.getId());
        assert userFromDB.getStates().size() == 2;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name="tbl_users")
class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id

    @Column(name="user_name")
    private String name

    @ManyToMany
    private Collection<State> states = Lists.newArrayList()

    // Getters and setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name="tbl_states")
class State {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name="state")
    private String state;
    // Getters and setters
}
```

You should change your mapping to @ManyToMany!

And you must have 3 tables on DB like this:
TBL_USERS, TBL_STATES and TBL_USERS_TBL_STATES

The TBL_USERS_TBL_STATES table is the default table name that Hibernate uses when a property is annotated with @ManyToMany. If you want to change the tablename of TBL_USERS_TBL_STATES, use the @JoinTable annotation too. See the docs [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#example-one-to-many-with-join-table)

With this configuration, you should be able to fetch a State from database, add it to a new User and then persist it. I made a unit test and It works!

Comment: are you saying to remove to @OneToMany configuration?

Comment: Yes, because you don't need it. What you really need is to assure that the intermediate table 'TBL_USERS_TBL_STATES' exists in your database. Hibernate will use this table to map the states of a user (the states collection)!

Comment: services_id ? Where is this field?

Comment: sorry it should say state_id

Comment: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "uk_g6pr701i2pcq7400xrlb0hns" 2017-07-07T19:14:07.462969+00:00 app[web.1]: Detail: Key (state_id)=(2) already exists.

Comment: Hi! I did some correction! It's not OneToMany, It's ManyToMany, since one user can have one or more states and vice-versa. And I put the code I used here to test your cenario! Hope that help you!

Comment: I tried this but it creates a user multiple times! like if the user being created chooses three states, it creates three users with the same information; duplicate records

Comment: omg it works now! I did a bit of googling and so I tried to create the user at first, and then update the states after creating the user, like in this example [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926053/hibernate-many-to-many-duplicates-same-record) and it works perfect! Thank you so much for helping me with this and being patient !

Comment: @Aria happy to help you! Good coding!

Answer (score 0):

In your case it might be better to use a manytomany association with  manytomany hibernate dont generate unicity constraint.

Hibernate auto generation scheme behavior is a little bit strange with onetoMany but you can use this workaround.

Try this:

```
@ManyToMany 
@JoinTable(name = "user_state") 
private List<State> states;
```

Comment: This didn't work, it kept creating multiple users at once ? Like if I choose 2 states, it creates 2 users with the same details (except id)

Comment: It should work, maybe your save logic is not correct, please add in your post  detail of all your business code, i need the whole picture.from user instanciation or loading until the persist and flush to database included the code around the adduser method.